# How to receive a 201 response code from XHR request?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I have this :

route :

```
Route::post('/send', 'MessagerieController@ajoutMessage')->name('send');
```

```
 xmlhttp.open("post", "/send",  true)
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", CSRF_TOKEN);
        
        xmlhttp.send(donneesJson)
```

and php controller :

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post'){
            $donneesJson = file_get_contents('php//input');
            $donnees = json_decode($donneesJson);

            DB::table('messages')->insert([
                'content' => 'lol',
                'user_one' => 1,
                'user_two' => 2
            ]);
```

I get a 200 response code but not 201. I do not understand it seems to block at the post server method verification because if I put the INSERT outside of the condition, data are inserted in db

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` return uppercase request method `POST` and if condition comparing with lowercase `post` so condition failed.Since your using laravel,laravel has built in method to check request type and also in your case `ajoutMessage` method only used for post request then no need to check request type because you have mentioned route specifically for post method .

```
if($request->isMethod('POST')){

      $donneesJson = file_get_contents('php//input');
      $donnees = json_decode($donneesJson);

       DB::table('messages')->insert([
                'content' => 'lol',
                'user_one' => 1,
                'user_two' => 2
            ]);

   return response()->json(["message"=>"inserted successfully"],201);
}
```

if you see isMethod implementation ,it internally convert param to uppercase.

```
 /**
     * Checks if the request method is of specified type.
     *
     * @param string $method Uppercase request method (GET, POST etc)
     */
    public function isMethod(string $method): bool
    {
        return $this->getMethod() === strtoupper($method);
    }
```

and json method params

```
 /**
     * Create a new JSON response instance.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $data
     * @param  int  $status
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @param  int  $options
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0);
```